# images didn't show in angular 10

Tags: angular

i am tring to add photo in my component i am using this code

```
<img src="~/assets/img/avatar2.png" alt="">
<img src="src/assets/img/user8-128x128.jpg" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 img-circle mr-3">
```

**but i received this error and the image didn't displayed**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The path seems wrong. You are pointing the src images to the wrong place probably, judging by the screenshots alone. Maybe you also are compiling this with a framework so you would need to point at some config file where the images are stored.

Comment: @adel It will be better to understand the problem if you put screenshots of the root project directory.

Comment: Adel, check the response of Agung. The reason is that angular, when compile create an index.html a severals javascripts files and copy all the files in your "src/assets" to a folder "assets" this is the reason because your images are in assets/img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is wrong

try this

```
<img src="assets/img/avatar2.png" alt="">
```